# Graph API dependant query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having the facebook username, I need the user ID to access his feed, so right now I'm using this call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/john.doe
```

which returns something like:

```
{
  "id": "612029xxx",
  "first_name": "John",
  "gender": "male",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/john.doe",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "username": "john.doe"
}
```

there I use the id to get links:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/612029xxx/links/?access_token=xxx
```

But I would like to **make a batch request with a dependant query** to make just one call:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/batch=[{"method":"GET","name":"do-me-first","relative-url":"?id=john.doe",{"method":"GET","relative-url":"links","depends-on":"do-me-first"}}]&access_token=xxx
```

but it gives me an error: `Cannot query users by their username (john.doe)`.

Why can I access the user info with the **username** in the single call, and not in the dependant one??

P.S.: Probably the second query hasn't been properly constructed, but since it is giving me this first error, I couldn't know!

Comment: you don´t get username or global id of a user anymore, and you should not use those for anything. only use the app scoped ids - after authorizing users.

Comment: I'm sorry... what would be an app scoped id?
And... By "you should" you mean that although I can retrieve that info with the first mentioned call, I shouldn't use it? why? thanks!

Comment: check out the changelog for information about app scoped ids: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: the question: how do you even get the username? (john.doe) - because you would have to know it, the api does not return it anymore for privacy reasons.

Comment: I have a json feed that includes facebook's user url. But I don't know where it comes from in the first place.
I've read through the app scoped Id introduction in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading. Does it mean that the ID that I'm getting through: `https://graph.facebook.com/john.doe` might not work eventually?

Comment: i would not rely on it. and i would immediately delete that json file if you are not sure all users agreed to you having it. data privacy and stuff. the proper way to read stuff from a user (feed) is to authorize the user with the correct permissions.

Comment: `username` field has been removed in API v2 – so it will work until next Friday, and not any more after that.

Comment: +1 with CBroe. username field will not be available after next friday and hence you should not be using it anymore.